# the_author_meta() wont show inline text in { }

Tags: php, wordpress

In the array I have two users, and foreach user the meta variables holds 30,20,40 and 10,5,15.

Why are the variables not displayed inline?

My code:

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
  $boern = the_author_meta('boern',$user->ID);
  $voksne = the_author_meta('voksne',$user->ID);
  $vegetarer = the_author_meta('vegetarer',$user->ID);
  echo "<p> {$user->display_name} har tilmeldt {$voksne} voksne, {$boern} børn og {$vegetarer} vegetarer. </p>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
302040

John har tilmeldt voksne, børn og vegetarer.

10515

Hans har tilmeldt voksne, børn og vegetarer.
```

If instead I say:

```
$boern = 1;
$voksne = 2;
$vegetarer = 3;
```

It works just fine.

Comment: It depends on styling and floats i guess but can you show what exactly is result from inspector in your browser?

Comment: 302040

<p>John har tilmeldt voksne, børn og vegetarer.</p>

10515

<p>Hans har tilmeldt voksne, børn og vegetarer.</p>

Comment: I got it now :) Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your output, the meta data is printed first because `the_author_meta()` echo's the value, to get or assign the value to a variable you should use `get_the_author_meta()` function. Here is the updated code, I think this fixes your issue

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $boern = get_the_author_meta('boern',$user->ID);
    $voksne = get_the_author_meta('voksne',$user->ID);
    $vegetarer = get_the_author_meta('vegetarer',$user->ID);
    echo "<p> {$user->display_name} har tilmeldt {$voksne} voksne, {$boern} børn og {$vegetarer} vegetarer. </p>";
}
?>
```